# How to add a keyboard shortcut to the Team->Add command in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, egit

I would like to have keyboard shortcuts to Team->Add and Team->Commit in eclipse. I am using eGit.

I added them in Preferences->General->Keys and that works in that the keys show up on the menus next to Team->add and Team->commit.

However, when I press the keys nothing seems to happen. The little Key Assist window pops up after the first key and shows me the matching commands, with 'Add to Git index' included, but the file is not added to the git index.

More generally, I would like to be able to commit the current project to git without having to use the mouse.

Comment: I get the same problem - keyboard shortcut set up, no conflicts, proper scope ("In Windows"), but nothing happens when the keys are pressed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure that the Git command groups are available. Right-click a blank area of menu bar -> Customize perspective -> Command groups availability; make sure the 'Git' entry in the available command groups is selected.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thanks! I did not know that whole "customize perspective" even existed.

Comment: in Eclipse Juno you can find "customize perspective" under "Window" menu option

Comment: @JeremyS. Thanks a lot, Jeremy! Couldn't find that.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a keyboard shortcut in eclipse, you also have a scope attached to it (the "When" field, in Eclipse terms). Make sure that it's set to a scope that'll be in use when you fire the shortcut, like "Java editors" or the more broad "In Windows". (NB: I've not had a chance to test this myself, so I could be barking up the wrong tree).

Comment: More specifically, "When = in Windows, Category = Git, User = U".